# some PostScript specials could not be rendered (tcolorbox+DVI)

Tags: tikz-pgf, dvi, tcolorbox

I can't see `tcolorbox` in DVI file after running LaTeX. The error is

```
"MiKTeX Problem Report Message: Some PostScript specials could not be
rendered. Data: Error: /undefined in pgfo Operand stack:   
--nostringval--   PermitFileReading   --nostringval--   PermitFileWriting   --" ...
```

The same problems occurs when drawing something with the TikZ package. Since `tcolorbox` is related with TikZ, this error happens.

My setup:

- MiKTeX 2.9 (it's required to run LaTeX, not PDFLaTeX or TeXify)
- WinEdt 2.9
- Yet Another Previewer 2.9.4206

Comment: Can you show a minimal example?

Comment: Does the following link help: http://meyavuz.blogspot.de/2011/10/some-postscript-specials-could-not-be.html

Comment: egreg, of course! Here is the minimal example:  
`\begin{tcolorbox}  
This is another \textbf{tcolorbox}.  
\tcblower  
Here, you see the lower part of the box.  
\end{tcolorbox}`

Comment: Sorry but this isn't a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). What happened if you convert the dvi file to pdf?

Comment: Dear Marco, thank you! Your link helped. Sorry, my mistake. There aren't **working** examples before. Answer on your question: only text inside the box will appear in PDF.